# Why is pandas inserting spaces in my histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

Example data can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6160029/visanal_so.csv) in CSV format.

Given the following code:

```
figure()
grp.vis.plot(kind='hist', alpha=.5, normed=True)
show()
```

I obtain the following figure:

[image]

Why is pandas inserting gaps in the figure?  The values range from 0 to 7, and are all represented, so I see no reason why this should happen.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because parameter `bins` with default value `10` is in [`hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html):

```
grp.vis.plot(kind='hist', alpha=.5, bins=7, normed=True)
```

[image: graph]

If omit `rwidth`:

```
grp.vis.plot(kind='hist', alpha=.5, bins=7)
```

[image: graph1]

[Docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

> **bins** : integer or array_like, optional
>
> If an integer is given, bins + 1 bin edges are returned, consistently with numpy.histogram() for numpy version >= 1.3.
>
> Unequally spaced bins are supported if bins is a sequence.
>
> default is 10
>
> **rwidth** : scalar or None, optional
>
> The relative width of the bars as a fraction of the bin width. If None, automatically compute the width.
>
> Ignored if histtype is ‘step’ or ‘stepfilled’.
>
> Default is None

Comment: Note that the picture is giving something a bit different to what was intended. Just try:grp.vis.value_counts()

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for a bit of off-topic self-promotion, but perhaps you might find useful my library **physt** (see https://github.com/janpipek/physt ). Among other features, it provides different binning schemas, one of which ("integer") is suited for automatic "bins" for integer data.

```
import pandas as pd
import physt

df = pd.read_csv("visanal_so.csv")
ax = physt.h1(df.vis, "integer").plot(density=True, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency");
```

[image: What you get]

P.S. Note that the plot is similar to the original but dissimilar to what @jezrael shows. The automatic pandas binning behaves somewhat strange and definitely not in the way you intended.

Comment: much appreciated.  I'll be sure to check it out.